# How to resize the Smart-Tags panel to a bigger size when used on a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, designer, smart-tags

I have coded a usercontrol with a smart-tags panel for design time support.

All is well excepting the size of the panel is not quite big enough. Is there a way to force a size on this panel?

I'm looking for a programmatic way.

---

**UPDATE**:

For now, the only way I know is to add the following to the ***GetSortedActionItems()*** method :

```
const int numCharsForSpacing = 30;
new DesignerActionTextItem (new string ('\x01', numCharsForSpacing ), null),
```

This adds non-displayable characters text thus expanding the panel.

Sorta Hackish.... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one have an answer, I'll provide one and mark it as the accepted answer until someone provides a better solution.

For now, the only way I know is to add the following to the ***GetSortedActionItems()*** method :

```
const int numCharsForSpacing = 30;
new DesignerActionTextItem (new string ('\x01', numCharsForSpacing ), null),
```

This adds non-displayable characters text thus expanding the panel.

Sorta Hackish.... ;)